# Is it possible to list principals for all the databases in an ADX cluster with a single command?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The command `.show database <DatabaseName> principals` lists principals only for a specific database. I am trying to list principals for all the databases in a cluster. Something like `.show database * principals`. But clearly this command doesn't work. Is there any such command that can return me the desired result? I want a single list for all the principals for all the databases.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020-04-01 23:49 UTC, there's no such command.

Feature requests can be submitted to https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice